# How to assess a Windows Service hosted WCF service from another WCF service hosted in IIS7?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have done a work which contains two parts

1. WCF service which is hosted in Windows Service
2. WCF service project hosted in IIS7
   I have done both comfortably,But i got a problem?
   I want to call a method from WCF service hosted in WS from the 2nd WCF service hosted in IIS, but i was unable to do that? Can anybody help in this?

Comment: If you are consuming windows service wcf in iis7 then you need to provide access permissions to network users as well otherwise in some cases you may face problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure a client endpoint in the service being hosted in IIS to the service being hosted as a Windows service, and make your call through a proxy just as you would normally make a call to a WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your service hosted in IIS7 wants to call the other service, it needs to become a client of that other service.

So basically, in Visual Studio or on the command line, you need to create a service reference to your second service, so that you'll get a client-side proxy class, which you can then use to call the second service. Also, you will need to add some configuration settings to your `web.config` for the service hosted in IIS7 in order for it to be able to call the other service (in a Windows service).

So where exactly are you stuck??

Comment: Can you give me any link which helps me for doing that? i was searching for that? It seems to be quiet odd as iam new to WCF

Comment: You are almost coming to my answer

Comment: @febin: **where** are you stuck?? Which part don't you "get", don't you understand?? This is just creating a normal WCF client - like any other WCF client.....